# Java JDI casting to actual real type

Tags: java, jdi

I am just starting to figure out JDI a little bit for creating a custom debugger. I have been trying to convert reference objects into real objects, so I can access their fields or methods without using invoke. I include the jar into the project from the target vm so I have access to all of the real objects. I then try to cast but get the exception like `com.sun.tools.jdi.ObjectReference cannot be cast to myobject`. Is there any way to do something like this or do you have to use invoke?

```
User user = (User) frame.thisObject();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of cast is not possible at all because you have to think a debugger as an external process that doesn't know nothing about target program domain objects.
Your scenario is a special situation but usually debugger doesn't include target jars.

Comment: thanks for the info, I assumed as much but wanted to make sure. I will probably just create a similar object with the same methods and wrap the invoke calls up into something a little more friendly.